# Buy Narita Skyliner ticket on platform with foreign credit card

Tags: japan, tokyo, nrt

I went to Narita Airport and wanted to buy Skyliner ticket on platform (I've used Suica and entered the gate), but looks like the vending machine there didn't accept my credit card despite there's an option that says "buy with credit card". I used 3 credit cards, including Visa and AmEx, but none of them worked. After a bit of Googling, I saw [here](https://www.love-narita.com/entry/2017/01/skyliner-matome) that credit card was not accepted to buy Skyliner ticket on platform back in 2017. (Literally it says こちらでは現金・ICカード(チャージしてからの購入は不可)でライナー券を買えます(クレジットカード使用不可)。) Can anyone confirm it's still the case? Thanks!

Comment: There's also the issue that foreign credit cards are not accepted everywhere – a weird concept since AmEx, VISA and MasterCard are not Japanese companies, but you can be told "Only accepts Japanese VISA".

Comment: I've never had trouble with my Australian MasterCard (or Visa debit) in Japan. The ticket office might be able to help? Or you could buy a ticket online and then redeem it at the ticket machine: https://www.klook.com/en-AU/activity/1410-skyliner-tokyo/

Comment: I would note that the problem OP had was not that the credit card was foreign but rather that *no* credit card, foreign or domestic, was accepted at the kiosk.

Comment: My point was to get rid of the long line waiting outside Keisei turnstiles to redeem the ticket. Klook doesn't support buying liner ticket (aka limited express fare) only and use my Suica to pay for what they call base fare. The machines on platform doesn't allow redeeming tickets bought on Klook as well. Gene's answer pretty much explained my confusion. There might be a bug in their Kiosk payment system. Thanks!

Comment: I always reserve and pay online. Why not do that?

Comment: How did you reserve skyliner ticket online? I know JR ticket can be reserve online, but I don't think skyliner ticket can be reserved online.